# OpenGL compute shader premature abort after calling glComputeDispatch

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I have been trying to run a very simple counting compute shader to get a grasp on how many times my shader runs and how large of a compute array I can process.

It seems that I'm either hitting some driver limit or my shader takes too long for the card to execute so it is prematurely aborted or something. There does not seem to be any error returned from `glDispatchCompute` at least.

I have been reading up everything on compute shaders and nowhere does it seem to say that time limit would be an issue.

The hardware is an intel integrated graphics card which is rather low end but does have compute shader support. I want to be able to run compute shaders even on lower end cards and I think this card should be able to do it but I'm running into weird premature abort problems.

```
glxinfo | grep compute
GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage, GL_ARB_compute_shader, 
GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage, GL_ARB_compute_shader,
```

More info:

```
const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString(GL_RENDERER); // get renderer string
const GLubyte* version = glGetString(GL_VERSION); // version as a string
GLint texture_units = 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, &texture_units);
GLint maxAttach = 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS, &maxAttach);
GLint maxDrawBuf = 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_DRAW_BUFFERS, &maxDrawBuf);
GLint workGroupCount[3], workGroupSize[3];
GLint maxInvocations;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_INVOCATIONS, &maxInvocations);
glGetIntegeri_v(GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_COUNT, 0, &workGroupCount[0]);
glGetIntegeri_v(GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_COUNT, 1, &workGroupCount[1]);
glGetIntegeri_v(GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_COUNT, 2, &workGroupCount[2]);
glGetIntegeri_v(GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, 0, &workGroupSize[0]);
glGetIntegeri_v(GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, 1, &workGroupSize[1]);
glGetIntegeri_v(GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, 2, &workGroupSize[2]);

printf("Renderer: %s\n", renderer);
printf("OpenGL version supported: %s\n", version);
printf("Number of texture units: %d\n", texture_units);
printf("Maximum number of color attachments: %d\n", maxAttach);
printf("Maximum number of fragment shader outputs: %d\n", maxDrawBuf);
printf("Maximum work group invocations: %d\n", maxInvocations);
printf("Maximum work group count: %d %d %d\n", workGroupCount[0], workGroupCount[1], workGroupCount[2]);
printf("Maximum work group size: %d %d %d\n", workGroupSize[0], workGroupSize[1], workGroupSize[2]);
```

Output:

```
Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile  (0x416)
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
OpenGL version supported: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 17.0.7
Number of texture units: 32
Maximum number of color attachments: 8
Maximum number of fragment shader outputs: 8
Maximum work group invocations: 2048
Maximum work group count: 65535 65535 65535
Maximum work group size: 2048 2048 2048
```

Shader:

```
#version 310 es

layout (local_size_x = 32, local_size_y = 32, local_size_z = 1) in; 

layout (binding=0) uniform atomic_uint counter; 

void main(){
    atomicCounterIncrement(counter);    
}
```

Setup:

```
GLuint ac_buffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &ac_buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, ac_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, sizeof(GLuint), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, 0);

GLuint compute_shader = glCreateShader (GL_COMPUTE_SHADER);

std::string ss;
readfile("compute.cs.c", ss);
const char *shader_source = ss.c_str();
glShaderSource (compute_shader, 1, &shader_source, NULL);
glCompileShader (compute_shader);
printShaderInfoLog(compute_shader);
GLuint shader_program = glCreateProgram ();
glAttachShader (shader_program, compute_shader);
glLinkProgram (shader_program);
printProgramInfoLog(shader_program);
glDeleteShader (compute_shader);
glUseProgram (shader_program);

glBindBufferBase(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, 0, ac_buffer);

glDispatchCompute(1024, 1024, 1);
if(glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR) {
    printf("There was a problem dispatching compute\n");
}
glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);

glBindBuffer(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, ac_buffer);
GLuint *counter = (GLuint*)glMapBufferRange(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLuint), GL_MAP_READ_BIT);
printf("Counter: %u\n", *counter);
glUnmapBuffer(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER);
glBindBuffer(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, 0);
```

When I call `glDispatchCompute` with smaller values than `128` then I do seem to get reasonable results:

For example `glDispatchCompute(128, 128, 1)`results in `"Counter: 16777216"` which is consistent with `128*128*32*32`. But if I call it with a `256, 256, 1` - I get result that is `66811258` instead. Which is no longer consistent with expected `67108864`.

For smaller compute sets I always get expected results, but for larger ones the counter rarely ever goes beyond 60-100 million. Could I be hitting some driver limit? I though that since max group size is `65535` along each axis then I should be able to request large compute groups to be computed and expect all elements to be processed.

Could it be that my way of counting by means of atomic is flawed? Why does it still get reasonable results for small groups but falls short for large ones? How can I better debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you're just reading the result before computation is complete. You need an explicit call to `glFinish()` to force completion and can remove the call to `glMemoryBarrier()`. For OpenGL ES `glMemoryBarrier()` only deals with relative ordering on the GPU between stages, it doesn't enforce ordering relative to the client access.

The desktop OpenGL 4.6 spec supports `CLIENT_MAPPED_BUFFER_BARRIER_BIT` for synchronizing client-side access, but this isn't available for OpenGL ES.

Comment: Interesting. So why is it that glDispatchCompute takes so long time to finish? What does it wait for if not for the completion of the work?